# Lazy loading or preloading Angular modules and using a service worker to cache results?

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-router

Does the Angular CLI approach to progressive web apps include a way to cache preloaded or lazy loaded modules using a service worker (Progressive Web App) approach?

For example the Angular Router has a `PreAllModules` strategy, so just curios if this can be combined or is combined with service worker caching?

In other words configure the generated service worker to cache all resources preloaded with the `PreAllModules` strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe you can set up your ServiceWorker to lazy-load your modules in the background. The CLI provides tooling for this, see:

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

This article also provides a thorough explanation:

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-service-worker/

Comment: I didnt find any content of lazy-load modules with service worker in above two links.

Comment: the statement "ServiceWorker to lazy-load" is wrong here i guess. because SW is primarily used for the caching there is no lazy loading involved there.